# AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'select' - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am scraping the following URL to get list of countries/states

```
main_url enter = "http://www.shangri-la.com/shangrila/sitemap/"

for div in main_page_soup.select("div.main-content-area div.sitemap-4column-container"):

    for city in div.select("div.sitemap-box ul li"):

        for li in city:
            #print(li.find("a"))
            print(li.string)
            #print(li.select("a")["href"][0].text)
```

I can get the Names of countries by `print(li.string)` but I want to get the `a`' `href` values too.

I always used to do `print(li.select("a")["href"][0].text` but dont know for this site I get this error.

`AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'select'`

**What I want**
Scrape the links of countries inside those `LI`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `href` attribute of `a` tags, iterate `a` tags:

```
for div in main_page_soup.select("div.main-content-area div.sitemap-4column-container"):
    for city in div.select("div.sitemap-box ul li a"):
        print(city.string, city.get('href'))
```

There are `li` tags without `a` tag inside; causing the error.

Comment: @Umair, You're welome.